# Is there a theoretical maximum to physical pain?

Tags: science-based, brain

I'm imagining some form of torturer trying to maximise the pain of its subject, and what limitations (if any) would bound the amount of pain that could be caused.

The brain can only process a certain amount of sensory information (obviously), but I'm not sure if this is a limitation on the intensity that can be *perceived*.

Other than things like natural endorphins (that could theoretically be blocked by drugs by the torturer), is there anything that would limit the intensity of pain that a brain could experience?

Comment: For pain to be experienced, something needs to be there to experience it: for humans this is the brain--consciousness. A corpse or an unconscious person can't experience pain. Furthermore, at extremely high levels of pain, consciousness shuts down.

Logically, therefore, pain can't be infinite because at a certain point, there's no coherent consciousness to experience it anymore.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. I recommend you read the tag descriptions, as the use of reality-check is in this case incorrect. It would also help to include as much details as possible in your question. Painkillers exist, so it is possible to limit pain in one way or another. do you mean limiting the brain perception specifically or limiting the pain in general?

Comment: @JANXOL I've edited the question to try to make it a little clearer. I'm imagining a torturer trying to maximise the pain of the subject & what limitations there are to the pain that can be inflicted. Natural painkillers (i.e. endorphins) shouldn't be taken into account as they could theoretically be blocked.

Comment: @dragongeek but if someone is directly sending pain signal to a brain, I wonder if there’s a way to suppress the shutdown? Is high pain something you can force someone to gut through? I do not know the biochemistry involved.

Comment: Essence of question: is there always a higher level of agony that you could make someone experience even when they’ve experienced what they think is the worst?

Comment: @SRM That might be a better way of wording the question, yeah. Thanks.

Comment: Pain is based on your psychology and grasp on life. A person that has accepted death can't be tortured as well as a person with a reason to live. After a while pain is just another nerve signal that can be blocked by the brain, they either need time to recover or a reason to want to live to overwrite their pain signals so they take effect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Torture Questions are Gruesome content and thus Not-Allowable](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7973/we-cannot-host-gruesome-depictions-of-violence-the-torture-tag-has-it-and-nee)

Comment: Assuming that the question is serious: start with the Wikipedia article on [nociception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nociception) and work through the links and the cited sources. (And yes, everyone has a maximum pain threshold; once this threshold is reached, they lose consciousness.)

Comment: @Trish I'm not asking for an in-detail description of torture, but rather just speculation on the science surrounding it. I don't expect this to be particularly gruesome.

Comment: @productivesnail12 that doesn't matter. We don't do torture anymore since August. Your question boils down to "How to maximize pain under torture."

Comment: @AlexP Would it not be possible to prevent the brain from losing consciousness, though?

Comment: @Trish: Was I asleep? When did the powers that be post a list of allowable and not allowable subjects? AFAIK, all we have a strong suggestion to avoid "gruesome" content. A discussion of [pain theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_theories) and [pain scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_scale) is most definitely *not* gruesome; if anything, it's rather dry and somewhat tedious.

Comment: Losing consciousness is a protection mechanism. It can be blocked, but then the subject will just go into shock and die. Seriously speaking: I won't write an answer on this site, but I gave you three links to good starting points in your research.

Comment: 1. This is not, at least as currently written, a "gruesome" depiction of anything. 2. Torture is a reality in many cultures and is thus a viable line of inquiry for writers, game designers, and anyone else engaged in worldbuilding. This **IS NOT A DISALLOWED TOPIC** in this forum. Voting to Leave Open.

Comment: @Trish -- The linked Meta discussion does ***NOT*** in any way say that queries about torture or gruesome content are not allowed in this forum. That was instigated by a random person from Stack Exchange and the Community, if you read the responses, puts paid to the OP's plaint. Please do not make that post out to be some kind of mandate or rule imposed on this Community!

Comment: @elemtilas [CesarM is community Manager.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/users/63098/cesar-m) Not a "random person from SE"

Comment: @Trish -- Also known as ["Valued Associate #679"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326611/announcing-the-arrival-of-valued-associate-679-cesar-manara).  Either way you look at it, this person is not from our Community; the discussion did not arise from within the Community; and no "rules" such as you imply were imposed from without the Community.

Comment: Also voting to leave this question open. The referenced Meta Q is a good reference to link to any question using the [tag:torture] or [tag:execution] tags as a reminder that there are ***limits*** to what we will host here - but it is not a totalitarian decision to avoid all torture or execution related Qs. This Q isn't asking how to achieve max pain (which hits that Meta reference square in the face) but what the physiological and mental limits are. Frankly, if the question would be suitable for [biology.se] or [medicalsciences.se], it's suitable here regardless the tag.

Comment: This question is horridly distasteful, but it does ask a clear, answerable question. And I cannot find any way that it is in actual violation of rules, such as i know. open, but *i* am avoiding it.

Comment: @Trish The thing is the question as worded is not about torture, it's about pain tolerance, which is a relatively mundane topic. The key difference here is that the question is not about "how" to torture someone, it's asking if someone is in that situation would they hit a "pain cap". If they had asked "how do I cause maximum pain to a human being", that would probably cross the line, but this is more about human physiological responses in general. It's an ugly question but it doesn't seem to be over the line.

Comment: Additional comment about whether or not this question should be closed should first consider [A proposal to establish policy regarding the torture and execution tags](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8170/40609). This question should have been tagged [tag:torture].

Answer (score 5):

### You might use an analogue to Capsaicin, one which stimulates all pain receptors, not just heat receptors.

[Capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin) chemically stimulates the heat sensing nerves so that they uncurl just as they do in response to high temperature. The brain interprets the result as a burning sensation, just as if they were actually at a high temperature. Capsaicin is the active component in chili peppers.

Pain receptors certainly include heat sensors **burning hurts**, but there are several types. You would need a chemical cocktail to activate all of the pain receptors. For example, many of the bodies pain receptors respond to inflammation in nearby tissue.

Ultimately you could develop technology that simply stimulates the appropriate sensations directly in the brain via electrical signals. This would be the most effective because you could quickly turn the pain on/off as needed. This ability would be more effective in torturing than simply constant high levels of pain, because of the additional control over the psychology of pain. Also, you would have more control over pain levels allowing you to maximize all forms of pain over the entire body.

However, you cannot assume that just because the pain is not due to the body being damaged, that you can do this to a person without physical consequence. The body will response to *artificial* pain just as it does to *real* pain (which is only logical if the net result is the same according to the brain).

A second limitation is that people pass out in response to pain. This is the basis for some forms of fainting. The level of pain needed to do this varies widely. Perhaps you need to study this response to determine the threshold of pain to induce this response in any given person

Like many medical conditions, you could also treat the underlying symptoms associated with fainting. In particular, giving the patient oxygen can reduce the likelihood of fainting, as could treatment altering blood pressure and blood sugar. Reduce fainting, increase overall pain.

Answer (score 2):

Every square inch of your has, on average, 200 pain-receptor nerves. You also have a variable amount of pain receptors inside your body (ex. high amounts in the GI tract and chest, much lower in the interior of the legs). The theoretical greatest single physical pain one could ever experience would be to have a torturer stimulate every single pain receptor at the same time. Doing so through normal means would cause the prisoner to die, however. But, if you were writing Sci-Fi, there could be some machine that would cause the pain receptors to fire despite no immediate problem that would normally cause them (think of it like your nerves are firing, telling you something is hurting your body, but there is no actual physical damage to your body). That would leave the prisoner in the greatest possible physical pain a human could ever experience with no physical damage beyond probably shock, PTSD, extreme stress, etc.

That said, I'd argue from a story-perspective emotional or psychological pain, if done well, is much more effective and horrifying than any physical torture.